# How to remove hibernate-jpa-2.0 from JBoss

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, jboss

I am developing a web app with JSF using Jboss Tools, Hibernate, Mysql, Maven and Eclipse.

I already add hibernate-core dependency in maven.

But when I try to do a conection test I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

And I realized that the hibernate maven dependency has hibernate-jpa-2.1, but JBoss has hibernate-jpa-2.0, so this is an incompatibility error.

How can I remove hibernate-jpa-2.0 from JBoss library ?

Comment: You should rather use JPA provided by JBoss (unless of course you need something especially from 2.1). So better would be to fix dependencies to point to correct jpa rather removing jboss one. Otherwise you will have to pack separate jpa provider with your app, instead of using potentially more tested one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. You can use `dependencyManagement` ([docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)) to override the version numbers that your project should use. Create a dependency for hibernate-jpa-2.1 in there and (as long as `groupId` and `artifactId` are the same), the version here should override the versions in any dependent POM.
2. Use `exclusions` to get rid of unwanted transient dependencies ([docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html))